# keras embedding vector back to one-hot

Tags: decode, keras, embedding, one-hot-encoding

I am using keras in NLP problem. There comes a question about word embedding when I try to predict next word according to previous words. I have already turn the one-hot word to word vector via keras Embedding layer like this:

```
word_vector = Embedding(input_dim=2000,output_dim=100)(word_one_hot)
```

And use this word_vector to do something and the model gives another word_vector at last. But I have to see what the prediction word really is. How I can turn the word_vector back to word_one_hot?

Answer (score 3):

This question is old but seems to be linked to a common point of confusion about what embeddings are and what purpose they serve.

First off, you should never convert to one-hot if you're going to embed afterwards. This is just a wasted step.

Starting with your raw data, you need to tokenize it. This is simply the process of assigning a unique integer to each element in your vocabulary (the set of all possible words/characters [your choice] in your data). Keras has convenience functions for this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
max_words = 100 # just a random example, 
# it is the number of most frequently occurring words in your data set that you want to use in your model.
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
# This builds the word index
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['column'])

# This turns strings into lists of integer indices.
train_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['column'])

# This is how you can recover the word index that was computed
print(tokenizer.word_index)
```

Embeddings generate a representation. Later layers in your model use earlier representations to generate more abstract representations. The final representation is used to generate a probability distribution over the number of possible classes (assuming classification).

When your model makes a prediction, it provides a probability estimate for each of the integers in the word_index. So, 'cat' as the most likely next word, and your word_index had something like {cat:666}, ideally the model would have provided a high likelihood for 666 (not 'cat'). Does this make sense? The model doesn't predict an embedding vector ever, the embedding vectors are intermediary representations of the input data that are (hopefully) useful for predicting an integer associated with a word/character/class.